# How to get total count of grouped files along with the extension and path in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have mulitple directories and for each directory i want to list the total count of files grouped by their extensions, like follows:

```
/Documents
  2 zip 20 M
  3 tar 50 M
  5 png 10 K
/Desktop
  5 txt 10 K
  7 png 5 M
  10 jpg 5 M
```

---

The following script is my approach, but it's output differs from what i expect:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | while read -d '' -r dir; do 
    num=$(find $dir find . -type f | sed -n 's/..*\.//p' | sort | uniq -c); 
    printf "%5d files in directory %s\n" "$num" "$dir"; 
done
```

Script Output:

```
 7 csv
  1 csv#
  2 doc
  1 docx
  9 html
 24 jpg
 33 js
 20 mp3
  2 mp4
  9 pdf
101 png
  3 ppt
128 swf
  3 xml
  4 xsd
 26 zip
```

Comment: If GUI is option, check https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your script, I get the idea that you just want to go one level deep. So, why not try something like this:

```
for dir in * ; do
    if [ -d "$dir" ] ; then
        echo "$dir"
        extlist=`ls $dir | sed 's/.*\.//' | uniq`
        for ext in $extlist ; do
            qty=`qty=`ls "$dir/*$ext"| wc -l`
            space=`du -ch "$dir/*$ext"| sed -n 's/ *total//p'`
            echo "$qty  $ext  $space"
        done
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks @Ljm. But im getting errors while executing your script. Here is the error: ./fileCount.sh: line 9: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
./fileCount.sh: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file. Here is bash error: $ shellcheck myscript Line 7:space=`du -ch "$dir/*$ext"| sed -n 's/ *total//p'`^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this simple command.>> ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this backtick expansion. Fix to allow more checks.Line 12:^-- SC1072: Fix any mentioned problems and try again.$

Comment: It was a quick& dirty solution, but you seem to have missed the back-tics around the du|sed. Because back-tics are frowned upon, you might `space=$(du -ch "$dir/*$ext"| sed -n 's/ *total//p')`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
$ mkdir Desktop Documents
$ for d in D*; do for e in zip jpg foo; do for i in $(seq 1 $((RANDOM/3000))); do touch $d/$i.$e; done; done; done
$ declare -A a; for d in D*; do a=(); for f in $d/*.*; do (( a[${f##*.}]++ )); done; printf '%s: ' "$d"; declare -p a; done;
Desktop: declare -A a=([jpg]="3" [foo]="5" [zip]="3" )
Documents: declare -A a=([jpg]="6" [foo]="2" [zip]="2" )
```

You can parse the counting array as you see fit at the end of each iteration of the outer loop.